How to Solve Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT
I studied an Android Development course in the past weeks and I am trying to develop an app.
The app should starts an activity after unlocking the screen from sleep state.
From what I understood, the correct way to implement this function would be through the BroadcastReceiver class, with method onReceive().
From what I understood, any message from Android received through this message should be able to start a foreground activity, right?
Specifically, I wrote:
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("MyUnlockReceiver", "Received intent: " + intent.getAction());

     if (Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT.equals(intent.getAction())) {
          // some code
     }
}

But I get the following message in the logcat:
Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT flg=0x24200010 } to com.remembertobreathe.app/.ScreenUnlockReceiver

I there a way to start a foreground activity (in this case, showing an image) when the unlocking action happens? If not, what kind of workarounds could I use?
I thought that this intent was not considered a background execution.
Best
Luca

That's incorrect on modern Android.  Starting foreground activities has been limited.  See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts
Random BroadcastReceivers and background Services cannot start Activities except in relatively limited circumstances.  There was a time that code would have worked, but not anymore.

Thank you for your help Gabe. Is any other idea that come to your mind to achieve the same effect, or should I abandon in your opinion?

Two possibilities.  One is to request SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW.  This permission must be granted manually by the user, but it allows the app to draw UIs when it otherwise can't.  The other would only work if this is a personal app (it won't be allowed on the Play Store), but it would be to implement an AccessibilityService and be set as an accessibility app on the device.  This gives it similar heightened permissions to show the UI, but is not allowed if you aren't actually providing accessibility support.
